# Flask test client and unittest: mocking global object?

Tags: flask, mocking, python-unittest

I have a flask application which uses a global object `data_loader`.

The main flask file (let's call it `main.py`) starts as follow:

```
app = Flask('my app')
...
data_loader = DataLoader(...)
```

Later on, this global `data_loader` object is called in the route methods of the webserver:

```
class MyClass(Resource):
    def get(self):
      data_loader.load_some_data()
      # ... process data, etc
```

Using [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html), I want to be able to patch the `load_some_data()` method. I'm using the flask [test_client](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.test_client):

```
from my_module.main import app

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.client = app.test_client('my test client')
```

How can I patch the `data_loader` method in subsequent tests in `MyTest`? I have tried this approach, but it does not work (although the `data_loader` seems to be replaced at some point):

```
 @unittest.mock.patch('my_module.main.DataLoader')
 def my_test(self, DataLoaderMock):
     
     data_loader = DataLoaderMock.return_value
     data_loader.my_method.return_value = 'new results (patched)'

     with app.test_client() as client:
         response = client.get(f'/some/http/get/request/to/MyTest/route', 
                               query_string={...})

     # ... some assertions to be tested ...
```

It seems the `data_loader` is never truly replaced in the Flask app.

Also, is this considered "good practice" to have a global variable in the Flask server, or is the app supposed to have it stored inside?

Thanks

Comment: thank you. good luck  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `mocking`, [patch.object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) can be used to modify object attributes:

```
@unittest.mock.patch.object(data_loader, 'my_method')
def my_test(self, my_method_mock):
    my_method_mock.return_value = 'new results (patched)'
    with app.test_client() as client:
        response = client.get(f'/some/http/get/request/to/MyTest/route', 
                              query_string={...})

        my_method_mock.assert_called() # ok!
```

My solution with interesting insights would be:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get(self):
        client = app.test_client('my test client')
        patcher = patch('{package_here}.{module_here}.DataLoader.load_some_data', return_value={'status': 1})
        patcher.start()
        self.assertDictEqual(client.get('/').json, {'status': 1})
        patcher.stop()
        # or
        with patch('{package_here}.{module_here}.DataLoader.load_some_data', return_value={'status': 1}):
            self.assertDictEqual(client.get('/').json, {'status': 1})
```

About "good practice" and global variables. Yes, I have seen global variables in various projects. But I don't recommend using global variables. Because:

- It can lead to recursive imports and dependency hell. I have worked with large `Flask` application with recursive imports. It is really pain. And you can't fix all problems for a short time.
- Let's imagine you have a tests which `mocking` a [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336090/mocking-a-global-variable). I think refactoring is more difficult when you have a rather big service.
- Separate imports and initialization is really simpler and more configurable. In this case all works in one direction `import all dependencies` -> `load config` -> `initialization` -> `run`. In other case you will have `import -> new instance -> new instance -> import -> ...`.
- Another reason for memory leaks.

Maybe global variables is not bad way for a stand alone `packages`, `modules` etc but not for a project. I also want to recommend using [some additional tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52587523/how-can-i-manage-extra-modules-in-app-factory-pattern/52644503#52644503). This will not only make it easier to write tests, but it will also save you headaches.